How to test if child component was clicked?
I need to test (not trigger) if a click is done inside or outside a child component, including the DOM elements from this child and the sub-children.
I was using this code inside the child component with a ref on the main <div>, it works well, but I need the test to be executed from the parent element and it doesn't work this way :
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside);
    }

methods: {
    handleClickOutside(event) {
            let targetElement = this.$refs.element;
            if (!targetElement.contains(event.target)) {
                console.log("click")
            }
        },
}

When trying to add the same code in the parent with a ref on the component, I get the error : targetElement.contains is not a function.
I guess this is because the Vue component doesn't implement the contains method, so is there a way to achieve the same test from the parent side ?

If "targetElement " is DOM element, I'd expect it to work. It's just DOM element, Vue cannot affect this. The problem is not reproducible at this point

Just use an event handler in the template on the parent element <div @click="handleClickOutside">...</div>. Since the click event is bubbling you will get clicks from the div's children elements.
